# Why won't my MacBook find updates?

Tags: macos, updates, macbook-pro, macos-ventura

My MacBook doesn't find updates through software update. I noticed this happening with Monterrey (12.0) and it's still happening now with Ventura (13.0).

The latest version of macOS as of the writing of this post is 13.2, but in spite of being in 13.0, when I check for updates Software Update tells me I'm up to date:
[image: I'm up to date].

The only way I can update my software is by:

- Going to the App Store page for the latest macOS version
- Hitting "Get". This asks if I want to download the latest version [image: download the latest version]
- Downloading what seems to be the whole installer, as if I were upgrading [image: the whole installer]

I did this to get updates for Monterrey, and I'm about to do this because I need to update Ventura to 13.2, but it is very annoying I have to. Has anyone seen this before? Any ideas why this might be happening and what a fix could be?

Edit: I'm my Mac is a 2020 M1 MacBook Pro (MacBookPro17,1 Model No: G11C3LL/A).

Comment: How old is your macbook? 
https://macresearch.org/fix-no-updates-available-on-mac/

Comment: @nicepen it's a 2020 M1 MacBook Pro (MacBookPro17,1 Model No: G11C3LL/A). I'll edit the question to add this info there. Of the suggestions in the link the only thing I haven't tried is using safe mode. If I get a chance I'll try it out soon.

Comment: Look in `System Settings > Privacy & Security > [Scroll way down to "Others"] > Profiles >` and see what configuration profiles you have installed. Configuration profiles can be used to point your Mac at a different Software Updates server, such as a corporate internal server, or enforce corporate policies blocking you from upgrading to a new OS version that has not been approved by the IT department.

Comment: @Spiff great idea! I have no configuration profiles installed though. This reminds me I used to be enrolled in the public beta program— I can't remember if with this machine or my previous one, but could that be a lead? Something Time Machine copies over?